# Prove the identity $\sum_{i=0}^n i(n-i) = {n+1 \choose 3}$ , by a combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics

This question was asked on an exam I made. In the answers they proved a bijection between the following sets:

$\def\N{\Bbb N}X_i = \{\,(a, i, b) \mid a,b \in\N ∪ \{0\}, 0 ≤ a < i, i < b ≤ n\,\}$ for $i \in \{ 0, 1, \ldots , n\}$

$Y = \{\,C \mid C ⊆ \N_{n+1}, |C| = 3\,\}$ where $\N_{n+1}=\{\,i\in\Bbb Z\mid 0\leq i\leq n\,\}$

and provided the following relations:

$f : \bigcup_{i=0}^n X_i \to Y : (a,i,b) \mapsto \{a,i,b\} $

$f^{-1}: Y \to \bigcup_{i=0}^n X_i : \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$  with $c_1 < c_2 < c_3 \mapsto (c_1, c_2, c_3)$

Could someone provide me with an explanation as to why these sets and relations were chosen?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you at least understand that $|X_i| = i(n-i)$ and that $|Y| = \binom{n+1}{3}$?

Comment: I've fixed your formatting (let TeX do complete formulas, nit isolated symbols; also use \{ and \} to get braces). If you are going to do combinatorics you do better to convert to the true faith of those who know that $0$ is a natural number rather than to the heretics who think they know otherwise; your life will be much happier.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The harmonic series would like to have a word with you about how 0 isn't always a natural number.

Comment: @Arthur That one cannot divide by $0$ is an inevitable consequence of the way multiplication of natural numbers works. This means that 0 has a singular role among the natural numbers, and in some contexts needs to be set aside, but it does not invalidate the quality of being a natural number. In (enumerative) combinatorics the natural numbers are the possible outcomes of counting (of sets that by construction are obviously finite), and as such 0 is a (founding) member.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I don't disagree that 0 can be a natural number. I just don't think that it naturally belongs there in every single context.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you yes I do its mostly the relation I struggle with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation here is to count the number of 3-element subsets in $\{ 0, 1, \dots, n \}$, hence the right hand side $\binom{n + 1}{3}$.

Now we think of another way to generate a 3-element subsets. We pick a "pivot" by fixing one of the element, say $2$. In the next step, we pick another one less than the "pivot", i.e. $0$ or $1$, and the remaining one greater than the "pivot", i.e. $3, 4, \dots , n$. Suppose for now this method generates all the 3-element subsets of $\{ 0, 1, \dots, n \}$.

In your setting, $X_i$ is the collection of triples with "pivot" $i$ generated by the scheme above, and $\bigcup _{i = 0} ^n X_i$ is all the subsets generated by the method above, as we vary the "pivot" from $0$ to $n$. The set $Y$ is simply the collection of 3-element subsets.

Your relation $f$ can be used to show that the two sets are equipotent. Notice that for any triple in sorted order, say $(1, 2, 3)$, we can always link them to the 3-element subset $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. Conversely, given such a set, we can always construct this sorted triple. So $f$ is a bijection between $\bigcup _{i = 0} ^n X_i$ and $Y$. In other words, picking a "pivot" then two other elements, one greater and one smaller than the "pivot" indeed generates all the 3-element subsets.

With the bijection established, note that for a fixed "pivot" $i$, as there are $i$ numbers less than it and $n - i$ greater, the number of triples for all the "pivot"s is
$$
  \sum _{ i = 0} ^n i (n - i) \, .
$$
Thus
$$ 
  \sum _{ i = 0} ^n i (n - i) = \binom{n + 1}{3} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation is a lot more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

By stars and bars, the number of $k$-uples $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ with $x_j\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $x_1+\ldots+x_k = n$ is given by $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. This is the same as stating that
$$ [x^n]\left(\sum_{m\geq 1}x^m\right)^k = \binom{n-1}{k-1} \tag{1}$$

$$ \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^k} = \sum_{n\geq k}\binom{n-1}{k-1} x^n \tag{2} $$

$$ \frac{x^{k}}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n\geq k}\binom{n}{k} x^{n} \tag{3} $$

so by considering the instance $k=3$ of $(3)$ we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k(n-k) = [x^n]\left(\sum_{k\geq 0} k x^k\right)^2 = [x^n]\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4} = [x^{n+1}]\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^4} = \binom{n+1}{3}.$$